# Significance of $CONDITIONS while running a sqoop command

Tags: sqoop

whats the importance of $CONDITIONS in every sqoop import query ?

ex:

```
select col1, col2 from test_table where \$CONDITIONS
```

What if I need to put my own where condition in the query and it works ?

Answer (score 1):

The significance is explained in the [Sqoop User Guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) and in [Apache Sqoop cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029519.do). To put it into nutshell, Sqoop needs a placeholder in the query to populate it with generated slices to enable parallel import.

Answer (score 0):

It will act as a place holder where sqoop replaces it to make the query works parallel. It is must to put $CONDTIONS when you are importing query results. Still you can place your condition as below,

```
Select col1,col2 from table where $CONDITIONS and "your condtion"
```

Note: you can directly see in stack trace what the condition sqoop places here at $CONDITIONS. Eg. The first thing you can see is the condition "where 1=0" to fetch the metadata or schema from source table.